# Dynamically built RadioButtonList displays text but not radio buttons

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I am dynamically creating a table that has many rows.  Each row needs to have a RadioButtonList where users can select "Under Review", "Accept", or "Reject".  However only the text is displayed:
[image: This is not what I want]

The code from the ASP page uses old-style ASP to display a variable:

```
                    <tbody>
                    <%=mstrSocialMediaList%>
                    </tbody>
```

Here is the VB code that builds mstrSocialMediaList:

```
            mstrSocialMediaList &= "<tr>"

            ... a bunch of table building code excerpted ...

            mstrSocialMediaList &= "<td><asp:RadioButtonList ID=""rbStatus" & .SocialMediaID & _
                """ runat=""server"" RepeatDirection=""Horizontal""> "
            '                mstrSocialMediaList &= " OnSelectedIndexChanged = ""rbSaveSocialMedia"">"
            mstrSocialMediaList &= "<asp:ListItem Value =""0"""
            If .StatusID = 0 Then
                mstrSocialMediaList &= "  Selected =""True"""
            End If
            mstrSocialMediaList &= ">Under Review<br /></asp:ListItem>"
            mstrSocialMediaList &= "<asp:ListItem Value =""1"""
            If .StatusID = 1 Then
                mstrSocialMediaList &= "  Selected =""True"""
            End If
            mstrSocialMediaList &= ">Accepted<br /></asp:ListItem>"
            mstrSocialMediaList &= "<asp:ListItem Value =""2"""
            If .StatusID = 2 Then
                mstrSocialMediaList &= "  Selected =""True"""
            End If
            mstrSocialMediaList &= ">Rejected<br /></asp:ListItem>"
            mstrSocialMediaList &= "</asp:RadioButtonList>"
            mstrSocialMediaList &= "</td></tr>"
```

When I examine mstrSocialMediaList in the debugger, it looks like this (I formatted it)

```
<tr>
<td>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbStatus163" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"> 
<asp:ListItem Value ="0">Under Review<br /></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value ="1"  Selected ="True">Accepted<br /></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value ="2">Rejected<br /></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</td>
</tr>
```

Just for the hell of it, I added the ASP code just above this line to the aspx page and it renders Just fine.  It also renders just fine if I stick it in the table.

[image: Looks fine!]

Can anyone help?
Many thanks,
Steve

Comment: You are attempting to send a string to the browser and have it turned into a control? I don't think you'll find that the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`asp:RadioButtonList` is a server control and if you pass this as a string it will not render properly in client side. You must dynamically create the control and add it to the Page's (or wherever you want it) Controls collection in code behind.

E.g.

```
Dim rbl as New RadioButtonList

'Create your list items as follows
rbl.Items.Add(New ListItem("Some text", "SomeText"))

Page.Controls.Add(rbl)
```

replace Page with Table cell ID if you wish to place the `RadioButtonList` inside a particular Table Cell.

Hope this helped!